# Link errors - unresolved token/external symbol for unmanaged C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, linker-errors

So I have a wrapper shown below:

Wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Engine.h"

namespace Wrapper 
{
    public ref class EngineWrapper
    {
    public:
        EngineWrapper();
        virtual ~EngineWrapper();
    protected:
        !EngineWrapper();
    private:
        CEngine *m_engine;
    };
}
```

Wrapper.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
using namespace Wrapper;

EngineWrapper::EngineWrapper()
{
    m_engine = new CEngine();
}

EngineWrapper::~EngineWrapper()
{
    if (m_engine)
    {
        delete m_engine;
        m_engine = NULL;
    }
}

EngineWrapper::!EngineWrapper()
{
    if (m_engine)
    {
        delete m_engine;
        m_engine = NULL;
    }
}
```

and this is some of my native engine code (in another project):

Engine.h

```
class CEngine
{
    public:
        CEngine();
        virtual ~CEngine();

   // other stuff
}
```

Engine.cpp

```
CEngine::CEngine()
{
    // do stuff
}

CEngine::~CEngine()
{
   // do stuff
}
```

My Wrapper project is a C++/CLI project compiled using `/clr`
My Engine project is a native C++ project which produces a .dll, .lib, and .exp (from looking at the output when this project builds)

For the Wrapper project, I've added the location of the native .lib to the linker input.

My issue: I get the following errors:

```
Error   126 error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000380) "public: __thiscall
CEngine::CEngine(void)" (??0CEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
__clrcall Wrapper::EngineWrapper::EngineWrapper(void)" (
0EngineWrapper@Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)    C:\..\..\Wrapper.obj    Wrapper

Error   127 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
CEngine::CEngine(void)" (??0CEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
__clrcall Wrapper::EngineWrapper::EngineWrapper(void)" (
0EngineWrapper@Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)    C:\..\..\Wrapper.obj    Wrapper
```

As I think it is finding the library correctly, how come it doesn't recognize the native ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the CEngine class in the native C++ project, check this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx) for details

Comment: oh, duh. Yea, the class wasn't being exported. Thanks for that!